# Changing the plotted confidence intervals plotted for an ARIMA model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, predictive-models, arima, model

I'm having trouble changing what prediction/confidence intervals/bands are plotted when plotting a forecasted arima object generated.

> model <- auto.arima(x)
>
> forecast <- forecast(model, h=29)
>
> plot(forecast)

I see the call automagically chooses some standard intervals (maybe 90% and 95%?), but the documentation for forecast.Arima() and plot.forecast() don't seem to mention which they are and how to alter which are plotted. The closest I can see to it is in the plot.forecast() help page, you can change the colors the prediction intervals are shaded with.

Ideally, I'd like to see 70% and 90% bands on my 29 step-ahead forecast plot.

thanks!

Comment: you might want to look at a blog post which I helped craft   http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/you-should-have-50-confidence-in-your-confidence-limits which details some deficiencies in the standard computation of ARIMA/TF forecast uncertainties.

Comment: Interesting. What would you suggest I do in lieu of prediction intervals?

Comment: I have implemented a couple of things within AUTOBOX that resample the model errors and take into account pulses. They are still prediction intervals just a tad more realistic ( maybe a lot more realistic ! ). Have you ever noticed how tight the confidence intervals are from standard solutions ... including SAS , STATA and everybody else except AUTOBOX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lunch break, a think, and some good luck, I stumbled upon the answer! It's an option in forecast():

> forecast <- forecast(model, h=29, level=c(70,90))

where the argument *level* takes the appropriate confidence intervals.